# How to create a custom PopUp Menu 

Tags: android, popupmenu, android-menu

I would like to create a custom PopUp menu in Android like the one in the attached screenshot. Any pointers would be appreciated.

On click of the button "Choose Name" , you see a PopUp menu just below the button.

[image]
Thaknks.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at [building custom dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).  In Android, a `Dialog` is typically in the form of a popup window.  You can also do this with an Activity and apply the Dialog theme to it (mentioned in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)).

Comment: Pop window is a separate thing from the pop up menu

Answer (score 3):

Sana,

You will probably want to look into creating a custom `Dialog` for your application: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: @Sana it may be possible, but I feel the custom Dialog path would be simpler.  It seems nicholas agrees with me :]