# How do I programmatically add an image to Android PopupMenu()?

Tags: java, android, menu, popup

I would like to add  thumbnail images to each item in my popup menu.I am able to create my menu dynamically and add text items,how would I go about adding images, can you provide an example or direct me to some resources?

I want to do this without the use of an xml like I've done below.

Sample code ...

```
popupMenu = new PopupMenu(VideoPlayer.this, v); 
   if(bitRates != null){
       int menuItem = 0;
       popupMenu.getMenu().add(0,menuItem, 0,"Hide menu");
          for(int i=1;i<bitRates.size();i++){
              menuItem = i;
              popupMenu.getMenu().add(0,menuItem, 0,qualityList.get(i)+" : "+bitRates.get(i));
              Log.i("ITEM",qualityList.get(i)+" : "+bitRates.get(i));

          }
          popupMenu.getMenu().add(0,menuItem++, 0,"Back to home");

      }
  popupMenu.show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271942/how-to-create-a-custom-popup-menu) it seems it has to be done using [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).